# Fetching conf room info from AAD

Tags: azure, active-directory

I am trying to fetch conference rooms info from Azure Active Directory using REST API. So I have tried requests like the one given below but it did not return any result. I have tried a similar request for 'servicePrincipal' objects as well with no luck either. So I wonder if reuqesting conf rooms is supported in AAD REST API at all ?

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/contacts?api-version=2013-11-08&$filter=startswith(displayName,'Conf%20Room')
```

this queries for contacts with displayName starting with 'Conf Room' (assuming conf room displayNames in my organizations AAD start with 'Conf Room')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conference rooms that have mailboxes in Exchange are users in AD/Azure AD.

Query users not contacts.

```
HTTP GET https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/users?api-version=2013-11-08&$filter=startswith(displayName,'Conf%20Room')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Dushyant! that really worked. For some reason I was thinking that conf rooms should be as contact objects in AAD as opposed to user objects which represent real users and therefore even did not give a try to that request for user objects.